# Adding a get property that renders in a lightning-datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

I have an LWC that takes an object returned from the server-side, makes it mutable by cloning, and then adds a get property via [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
    const t = {...template};
    Object.defineProperty(
        t,
        'typeAndName',
        { get() { return t.type + ': ' + t.MasterLabel; } }
    );

    // Correct output here
    console.log('typeAndName', t.typeAndName);
```

But when rendered in a `lightning-datatable` (actually a `lightning-tree-grid` that is based on that) column:

```
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'typeAndName',
            label: 'Type and Name',
        },
```

an empty string always results.

Is this a step too far for LWC given that properties are reactive? Or am I missing something else here?

**PS**

Just looked at the code again and this cleaner [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) version does work so for me so the original question is just of academic interest now:

```
    const t = {
        ...template,
        get typeAndName() { return t.type + ': ' + t.MasterLabel; }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ get() { return t.type + ': ' + t.MasterLabel; } }
```

Should have been:

```
{ get: function() { return t.type + ': ' + t.MasterLabel; } }
```

You can also use a template literal here:

```
{ get: function() { return `${this.type}: ${this.MasterLabel}`; } }
```

The descriptor object is in normal object syntax, just as you'd say `{ message: 'Hello World' }`.

Here's a [working example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/r142AoytoJE8pWBvTGkH/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: So the (presumably) older syntax is needed not the (presumably) newer `get()` syntax? Good to know for other cases; think the spread is the way to go in this example. And +1 for the template literal us.

Comment: @KeithC Both `{ fn() {...} }` and `{ fn: {...} }` are supported even in older editions. The difference between the two is technical (the former is a named function, the latter is a property pointing to an anonymous function). For whatever reason, JS tends to distinguish between these two in some cases, and this is one of those cases. Unless the docs show otherwise, presume that only the latter method is supported.

Comment: Thanks, useful advice (as always).